# how to change the number of processes in multiprocessing.pool?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, pool

I want to change the number of processes in `multiprocessing.pool` but I don't see how to do so.
is there a way to do it or should I try to kill the old one and create a new pool with different number of processes, and if so, how can I kill the old pool? is using `close()` will suffice?

Answer (score 1):

There is a private method, [multiprocessing.pool._repopulate_pool](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a18227d96ee8/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l215) which can change the number of workers in the pool. However, I don't think you should use this. For one thing, since the name of the method starts with an underscore, it is a private method -- an implementation detail. In theory it could change in the future and break your code.

But perhaps even more importantly, your machine has a finite number of processors. In general, that's the ideal number of processes to use in your pool. If you have more than that, then your pool workers are going to fight amongst themselves for access to your CPUs. If your problem is CPU-bound, there is no advantage to having more workers than CPUs.

If you want to restrict the number of CPUs used by the multiprocessing pool, then it would be easiest to determine in advance what the hard limit should be and instantiate the pool to use that number of workers from the outset:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
```

Note also that `mp.cpu_count()` returns the number of processors available. If you do not set the `processes` parameter, `mp.Pool` will use `mp.cpu_count()` processes by default.